# Dynamics 365 for Operations Online trial APIs or Web services

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7

We have setup trial Dynamics for Finance and Operations. This is actually created from here.
https://aka.ms/D365OperationTrials - We have created Finance and Operations for Enterprise. 
So our URL for trial is https://d365try-31.trial.operations.dynamics.com/namespaces/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?mode=trial

Our requirement is to fetch data(order, accounts, companies and all data available there) in our custom application.

Is there any Web Service or Apis available to achieve this ?What kind of authentication we need to do?

We also want to customize ribbon to add some button and want to add custom code in this trial version. Is this possible ? if yes, how.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

a. To answer your first question, yes you can use Odata feed end points exposed by D365 Unified Operations and consume in your custom application. However, the pre-requisite for this kind of integration is you will need to register your application in AAD (Azure Active Directory) where you generate the client id and secret key which can then be used in your custom application for authentication purpose. For any kind of web service integration, be it REST, SOAP or ODATA, the registration process in AAD is mandatory.

b. In the trial version link which you have put in your question, you won't get a VM access. For that you will need to either be on the Microsoft Connect site, you will need invitation to join the feedback program.

We (www.dynamicsavenue.com) host Trial D365 VMs for developers and pre-sales consultants. If you are interested, drop us a line on [dilip]dot[nair]at[dynamicsavenue]dot[com]

Answer (score 0):

Refer link for Dynamics AX Integration samples and demos.
[Dynamics-AX-Integration](https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration)